# Dynamic Columns Names in Excel Destination (data flow)

Tags: excel, dynamic, ssis, ssis-data-flow

I'm trying to make my 'destination column' dynamic in an Excel Destination. The data inserted into the columns is always the same aswell as the amount and position of the columns. The reason for this is because my headers are multi-language. However the Excel Destination does not accept dynamic header names.

Is there anyway to make these dynamic or is there a different workaround for this.

For example the headers can be:

```
 PR_ID        PR_NAME        PR_PRICE
 1            Bag            9,00
 2            T-Rex Figure   15,00
```

But the headers can also be:

```
 PR_ID        PR_NAAM        PR_PRIJS
 1            Bag            9,00
 2            T-Rex Figure   15,00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 2 headers to fix this problem, row 1 = header for Excel Destination and row 2 = header for the user(cosmetic header). after adding all of this I used a script task to run an Excel macro to hide the 1st header row.

It now looks like this:

```
 PR_ID      PR_NAME       PR_PRICE     <- Hidden by Excel macro
 PR_ID      PR_NAAM       PR_PRIJS
 1          Bag           9,00
 2          T-Rex Figure  15,00
```

And if in English:

```
 PR_ID      PR_NAME       PR_PRICE     <- Hidden by Excel macro
 PR_ID      PR_NAME       PR_PRICE     
 1          Bag           9,00
 2          T-Rex Figure  15,00
```